# How can I make sure that an existing value is not overwritten when doing an ElasticSearch update in Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have an ElasticSearch entry with the ID `myId` in the index `myIndex`. This entry has the field `someExistingField`.

Now I want to update this entry. For technical reasons, the update request does not contain `someExistingField` data.

I want to make sure that in scope of this update

- only those values are changed that are specified in the update request and
- values not mentioned in the update request are not changed.

Currently I am using this code:

```
final Map<String, Object> esDocument = ...;

final UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest(myIndex, myId);
request.doc(esDocument, XContentType.JSON);

esClient.update(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

How do I need to change this code in order for it to not override existing values which are not specified in `request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
final UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest(myIndex, myId);
...
request.fetchSource(new FetchSourceContext(true, 
  new String[]{"someExistingField"}, Strings.EMPTY_ARRAY));
...
```